# How to run a query between two different datasources in Datagrip?

Tags: google-bigquery, datagrip

I'm using Datagrip as Editor from my data sources in Bigquery. Everything is ok when I add a project with a service account into datagrip and make queries only from this project. But when I want to make a query between to different tables from different projects or data sources of Bigquery, Datagrip doesn't allow me.
[image]

This is the query running in bigquery editor console
[image]

I follow these steps to connect a project from bigquery into a datasource in:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/07/10/using-bigquery-from-intellij-based-ide/

Comment: Is it possible to make a project where `peruhop-booking` and `peruhop-route-files` are in the same data source? 

For now you're trying to make a query between two different data sources.
We've got an [issue about it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8805)

Comment: A quick update, DataGrip supports BigQuery out of the box now, but still lacks of cross database joins.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want to do, as @Giacomo suggested, is join across different projects.

You can do this by adding multiple projects in one data source. Simply enter a comma-separated list of the desired projects in the `AdditionalProjects` setting in the BigQuery data source configuration under the "Advanced" tab.

Using your example, if your data source has `bombo` as the default project, then add the other two projects in one data source as illustrated below:

[image showing multiple projects for a BigQuery data source in DataGrip or Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zxH6.png)

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip [supports BigQuery](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/bigquery.html) out of the box since version 2021.1.

For cross database joins [follow the issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8805).

Comment: the issue is not about cross database joins, but rather about cross projects joins. Two different projects in the same BigQuery account.